Are all cats and dogs mammals equivalent to all cats or dogs are mammals?
Are all cats and dogs mammals equivalent to all cats or dogs are mammals? I ask because it seems they are not. For let C be the predicate cat. Let D be the predicate dog. Let M be the predicate mammal. So, we have ∀x(Dx→Mx)∧∀y(Cy→My)→∀x∀y(Dx∧Cy→Mx∧My), which is a tautology. As proof of this, check the following link: https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~6x(Dx~5Mx)~1~6y(Cy~5My)~5~6x~6y(Dx~1Cy~5Mx~1My) .
However, ∀x(Dx→Mx)∧∀y(Cy→My)→∀x∀y(Dx∨Cy→Mx∧My) is invalid. As proof, check the following link: https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~6x(Dx~5Mx)~1~6y(Cy~5My)~5~6x~6y(Dx~2Cy~5Mx~1My) .
I must also note I found something else weird: Let A, B, C, and D be any predicate. So, we have ∀x(Ax→Bx)∧∀y(Cy→Dy)→∀x∀y(Ax∧Cy→Bx∧Dy), which is a tautology. And as proof of this, check the following link: https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~6x(Ax~5Bx)~1~6y(Cy~5Dy)~5~6x~6y(Ax~1Cy~5Bx~1Dy)

Of course, not. If we only know that x is a dog or y is a cat it certainly does not follow that both x and y are mammals. Maybe x is a dog but y is a rock.

In first order classical logic, we may write the following:
1. ∀x(Dx → Mx)                  all dogs are mammals
2. ∀y(Cy → My)                  all cats are mammals
3. ∀x(Dx → Mx) ∧ ∀y(Cy → My)   all dogs are mammals and all cats are mammals 
4. ∀x((Dx ∨ Cx) → Mx)           every thing that is a dog or a cat is a mammal 

3 and 4 are logically equivalent. I understand your question to be asking, why do we use the disjunction ∨ in 4, when in English it is unnatural or even incorrect to say, "All dogs or cats are mammals" rather than, "All dogs and cats are mammals"?
The answer is that the word 'and' does not behave in English the same way that the conjunction ∧ works in formal logic. In English we can conjoin names (Alice and Bob), classes of things (dogs and cats), properties (tired and emotional), adverbs (slowly and steadily) and many other things. In logic, ∧ and ∨ are confined to operating on propositions or propositional formulas.
The English, "All dogs and cats are mammals," is understood as, "All dogs are mammals and all cats are mammals," not as, "All things that are both dogs and cats are mammals". Several words behave differently in natural language from how they would be represented in formal logic. This is particularly true when quantifiers, modal operators and conditionals are present. These create a kind of boundary within a sentence and some words have a tendency to cross these boundaries while others don't.
The result is, it is more difficult than it appears to translate English sentences into formal logic. But one of the advantages of formal logic is that it avoids ambiguous constructions.

I came here to say something like this. What I would add is that the relationship between the English word "or" and the logical "or" is even more complicated. "Or" as used in English is usually, but not always, closer to the logical "xor" than to the inclusive "or" in logic. That's a tangent, but a very closely related one.

As a native English speaker, I would say I’m skeptical that the second sentence (“all cats or dogs are mammals”) is even a grammatically valid sentence. I’m not sure there’s an “official” specification of English grammar anywhere, but the sentence just sounds weird and possibly ambiguous to me. So, the grammatical invalidity of the second sentence would imply that the two sentences are by definition not equivalent.

Heh. I was going to make a comment on the question that quoted that sentence and said "nobody ever says that". I decided not to, because I guessed that one might be able to come up with a different sentence that used "or" in a similar way but was better-formed. But I agree - no-one every says that.
